# onSizeChanged getting called with every recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I'm working on **compose** UI-based android app. I need to get the size of composable and do get size on every real change. I checked the base code of **onSizeChanged**. onSizeChanged creates modifier extending **OnRemeasuredModifier** and stores previous **size** but after every recomposition, the previous gets reset and this cause infinite calls of **onSizeChanged**. I tried composed but that didn't help. Here is a sample code:

```
var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
LaunchedEffect(key1 = counter, block = {
    delay(1000)
    counter++
})
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .onSizeChanged {
                it
            }
            .composed {
                Modifier.onSizeChanged {
                    it
                }
            },
        text = "Hello, $counter!",
        color = Color.Black
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: While the counter is less than 10 size is  `171 x 59` but `onSizedChanged` gets fired `10` times and `9` of them are useless cause the size is not changed that's because `onSizeChanged` is reinitialized after each `recomposition`. with `remember` the previous size won't get reset and `onSizeChanged` gets called only if the size is really changed.

Comment: I know it gets fired, but what problem does it causing you? E.g. if you write it value `mutableStateOf` and use in an other view, e.g. `Text`, the duplicated value won't cause extra recomposition.

Comment: In some use-cases, it may cause bad performance. e.g. imagine setting the height of Text, based on the height of another Text. Recomposition will be done infinitely and that's not good.

Comment: As I said it's not gonna trigger recomposition unless the value is actually changed. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/e2e1f66066f105459191a5d44a649221), `OtherView recomposition` log will only be called once on `1`, and then once on `10`

Comment: I know I could remember the size but if I wanna do some operations on the size, the operations are fired infinitely and that may be costly. I want to even reduce the calculations `onSizeChanged`. That's cause I'm looking to reduce calls of `onSizeChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented is to remember **onSizeChanged** Modifier to save the previous size. but I'm not certain that this is the correct way.

```
var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
LaunchedEffect(key1 = counter, block = {
    delay(1000)
    counter++
})
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .onSizeChanged {
                it
            }
            .composed {
                Modifier.onSizeChanged {
                    it
                }
            }
            .remembered {
                Modifier.onSizeChanged {
                    it
                }
            },
        text = "Hello, $counter!",
        color = Color.Black
    )
  }
}
```

I tried **composed** but that didn't help. So I created the **remembered** function:

```
@Composable
fun Modifier.remembered(modifier: () -> Modifier): Modifier {
    val rememberedModifier = remember {
        modifier()
    }
    return then(rememberedModifier)
}
```